# #import autocompletes but then says file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

I'm fairly new to `iOS` programming. In one of my projects, I created a group with an actual folder and placed a class extension, `UIPickerView+RAC` in that folder.

[image: Class extension I placed in my group]

---

Back in my view controller, I tried to reference `UIPickerView+RAC.h`. As you can see in the attached image, XCode's autocompletion picked up the filename.

[image: XCode's autocompletion finds the file I want]

---

However, XCode then gives me a compiler error saying that the file cannot be found.

[image: But then gives me an error that says file not found.]

---

What do I need to do guys? Any advice/help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rookie mistake. When I created the `Class Extensions` group and and linked it to the folder, I linked it to the opic folder instead of a `Class Extensions` subfolder. For some reason, any files created under that group would save into my `Documents` folder.

I created an actual `Class Extensions` folder, moved the files from my `Documents` folder and finally imported them in XCode. Everything compiled fine after that.